# How to query small client-side database in Node + Express

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite, csv, express

I am working on a simple Node/Express weather app in which the user can type in the name of a city and the program will query a weather server using the geographic coordinates of that city.
These coordinates are stored in a simple CSV file (city, country, longitude, latitude) which I have converted to an SQL database using SQLite.

My question is: *Is there a way to allow my App to load and query a DB locally (client-side) without resorting to a dedicated DB server?*

The reason I ask is because the DB is quite small (less than one MB) and it seems like overkill to use a dynamic server for this use-case. I tried finding a solution online, but couldn't come up with anything conclusive.

Comment: You can create a google sheet and interact with it directly from frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert your csv file to a json, then put it in your local project and make sure to export it with `module.exports`, after that you just parse it and use it.